# Batch Update BigQuery using PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am inserting into BigQuery using `$table->insertRows()`. Its fast and its working perfectly.

```
if(count($insertData)>0){
    $insertResponse = $table->insertRows($insertData);
    if ($insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
        foreach($ids as $rw){
            $mysqli->query("update insights set bigquery=NOW() where asset_id=".$rw['asset_id'].";");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I need to update data in regular basis. Since the number of data can range anywhere from 10k to 100k per day. I am sending 1000 update queries at once like this:

```
if(count($updateQueries)>0){
    $bigqueries = "";
    $mysql_queries = [];
    $i=0;
    foreach($updateQueries as $query){
        $i++;
        $bigqueries .= $query['bigquery']."\n";
        $mysql_queries[] = $query['mysql'];
        if($i>1000) break;
    }
    $jobConfig = $bigQuery->query($bigqueries);
    $job = $bigQuery->startQuery($jobConfig);
    foreach($mysql_queries as $qr){
        $mysqli->query($qr); // updating the local mysql table letting it know that the data is sent to bigquery
    }
}
```

But the update queries aren't working -- its not because there's error in the query itself. Is there a limit on how many queries I can merge into one query?

Is there a better way to batch update into bigQuery table?

Comment: Can you share the error message you got from running your code?

Comment: There's no error message at all. The code executes fine. but its super slow and many rows endup not executing and that causes data discrepancy. Now to solve that, what I did is, inserted the new "update" data AGAIN and remove the old duplicate ones doing this: `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE meta_api.insights AS (SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number) FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ad_id, asset_id, report_date, name) row_number FROM meta_api.insights) WHERE row_number = 1)`. I am not sure if this is the optimal solution. Is there any way I can stream update data into bigquery?